# Generating heatmaps based on multiple features in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
student    Time                              presence
  A      04/03/2022 21:52:55.446                 1
  A      04/03/2022 21:55:55.446                 0
  A      04/03/2022 21:56:55.446                 0
  B      04/03/2022 21:52:55.446                 1
  B      04/03/2022 21:55:55.446                 1
  B      04/03/2022 21:56:55.446                 0
```

I am trying to create a heatmap grouped by the student where X-Axis is time and Y-axis is a student. The color is based on the presence feature. I am confused between seaborn and calplot and not able to figure out how to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.heatmap`'s documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) mentions an example where pandas' `pivot` is used to create a heatmap of flights data. Here is an example of how it could be applied to the given data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_str = '''student    Time                              presence
A      "04/03/2022 21:52:55.446"                 1
A      "04/03/2022 21:55:55.446"                 0
A      "04/03/2022 21:56:55.446"                 0
B      "04/03/2022 21:52:55.446"                 1
B      "04/03/2022 21:55:55.446"                 1
B      "04/03/2022 21:56:55.446"                 0'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df['HourMin'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda t: t[11:16])
df_pivoted = df.pivot('student', 'HourMin', 'presence')
sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, cmap=['lightcoral', 'lime'], cbar=False, lw=2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap from long data]

Comment: After your previous comment I checked it and figured out a way to get to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: what does the t[11:16] indicate?

Comment: `lambda t: t[11:16]` takes a date string, e.g. "04/03/2022 21:52:55.446" and gives positions 11 till 16, or "21:52"